# Updating bokeh plot with output of another script

Tags: python, bokeh

My goal is to create a bokeh script that shows the processor and memory usage of several machines in my network. The first script pulls the cpu and memory usage, and the bokeh script shows a time series plot of these stats over the last few seconds.

I have copy pasted some bokeh code (thanks internet) that updates two plots in a line based on random numbers every 500 seconds:

```
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.driving import linear
from bokeh.layouts import layout
import random
tools = 'pan'

@linear()
def update(step):
    # Instead of random numbers, fetch stats from another script                                                      
    ds1.data['x'].append(step)
    ds1.data['y'].append(random.randint(0,100))
    ds2.data['x'].append(step)
    ds2.data['y'].append(random.randint(0,100))
    ds1.trigger('data', ds1.data, ds1.data)
    ds2.trigger('data', ds2.data, ds2.data)
# don't get this yet, but @linear is a decorator. Instead of having @linear(), we could also have                     
# update = linear(update)                                                                                             

p = figure(plot_width=400, plot_height=400)
r1 = p.line([], [], color="firebrick", line_width=2, legend='line1')
r2 = p.line([], [], color="navy", line_width=2, legend='line2')


ds1 = r1.data_source
ds2 = r2.data_source

curdoc().add_root(  p  )

# Add a periodic callback to be run every 500 milliseconds                                                            
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 500)
```

Let's assume the first script pulls tuples of memory/cpu usage every 500 ms, how would I get the bokeh script to fetch that information? Once I have that information, I'll be set.

The only idea I have right now is to write the output of the first script to a dict/json/h5 file, and have the bokeh script read it and append that data to the plot. I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Since the update script is just grabbing some numbers, your best bet is probably wrapping that thing inside an update function, processing those numbers so they fit a ColumnDataSource, then update the main CDS, which will then update the plot. Something like:

```
def update():
    # Do stuff to get new data
    numbers = get_usage()

    # Process new data into a CDS friendly format
    data1, data2 = process_numbers(numbers)

    # Update plot_source, this being whatever source is 
    r1_source.data = data1
    r2_source.data = data2

curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update, 500)
```

Comment: My concern with this is that every time a client accesses the bokeh website, it will start a new instance of the "get stats from nodes" functionality. I'd rather have one instance of the "get stats from nodes" functionality running whose results can be read by 10 clients.

Comment: Hmm, might be better then to do more like what you originally suggested, have a separate process running that just dumps into some flavour of sql db and then your bokeh page can just read from that when it's actually running. It would be better for storing historical data too if you wanted to look at the usage over some longer time frame.

Comment: I've not worked with sql dbs. I've touched mongodb briefly but not sure if that's related. Is there an example or tutorial somewhere? That would help a lot!

Comment: I've never used mongo so couldn't say anything for sure though I'd expect you can get the job done. I put off sql for a long time until recently but I think its been worth learning at least how to do the basics. [this](https://www.pythoncentral.io/introductory-tutorial-python-sqlalchemy/) seems a fairly good article. In the end it will probably depend on what you can be bothered to do, if you only need the recent history it'll probably be faster to just do it with json and save the time of learning sql, but if you have the time or can see needing more later it could be worth learning some sql.